# How to know Router's IP what connect to Modem

Tags: networking

I have a network like that:

`Internet <-> Modem <-> Router (broadcast wifi)`

I'm using Windows. If I use command: `ipconfig`, I only know Modem's IP through info of Default Gateway.

So, how to know the Router's IP in this network.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are able to access the admin interface of the router then you should be able to see the IP address of it's global port.  What make/model of router is it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the external (from the Internet IP) you can browse to http://www.whatismyip.com/ and check it there.
Or
You can check it inside the router's configuration page. Unfortunately you can't simply know it by being a member of its network since this is a limitation of the NAT and the IP protocol.

If you wish to know the router's IP inside the internal network of the router .
when running `ipconfig` it should be the `Default Gateway` entry.

Comment: Default Gateway after run `ipconfig` is 192.168.1.1. But, I browse with this IP, I'll access the Modem. I forgot my Router's IP what I configured before.  I want to configure Wifi again, but I dont know the IP. So, I cannot access the Router. Thats my situation.

Comment: From within the routers network you can't access the modem directly. I'm guessing what you are accessing is the router and not the modem. Try writing the whole `ipconfig /all` output

Answer (score 0):

If you know your IP and you know your Netmask, then you can easy find out the subnet. The Router's IP is "always" the first avaible IP in the subnet. Thats the case for your private IP.

For the public IP you can try a service like [this one.](http://whatismyipaddress.com/)